# Tiktok python bot ban : "Too many attemps", ban machine"

Tags: python, selenium, ip, proxies, tiktok

I would like to make a bot that create tiktok accounts.

So I created a program with selenium which will connect to a proxy and then go to the tiktok registration page, which enters all the necessary information (for the mail, I use temp-mail.org).

selenium is initiase like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
PROXY = "proxy:port"
chrome_options = WebDriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

But every time I have the same error : **"Too many attemps", ban machine"**

Sorry, I can't show image soo I give you a link :
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTECF.png)

However, I tried with a **vpn**, with **different web browser**, with **tor**, with **virtual machines** and **android emulators** but nothing work, there is always the same error.

I think my machine are banned (no by ip but by **hardwar**).

Can help me to change this or how to be disbanded please?

Thank you.

Comment: You're being rate limited. This means that your ip or account has been temporarily banned from accessing some feature. There are multiple ways to bypass rate limits for example using proxies. Most free proxies won't work when webscraping, as they're not being connected good enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is a problem with trying to sign into tik tok too many times in a short amount of time, I dont think there is anything wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

While attempting to login, re-login or creating an account ***TikTok*** platform may even wrongly identify you as a bot or spam and for the next 5 minutes or so, you may keep getting the *Too many attempts. Try again later.* error message when trying to sign in to TikTok as follows.

[image: TikTok_Too many attempts_Try again later]

To avoid getting detected as a bot you can use the following solution:

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
option.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
option.add_argument("window-size=1920,1000")
#optional : option.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
```